# Prove the positive sequence $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{1+\frac{a^2_n}{4}} $ is strictly increasing for $0 \leq a_0<\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$

Tags: real-analysis

My attempt:

$a_{n+1} - a_n=  \sqrt{1+\frac{a^2_n}{4}} -a_n > \frac{a_n}{2}-a_n = -\frac{1}{2}a_n$, which doesn't tell me any thing. How do I prove that this sequence is strickly increasing? Thank you!

Comment: $a^2 + b^2 \ge 2ab$

Comment: You have showed that it is decreasing

Comment: @TitoEliatron It was a type-o. I have corrected it.

Comment: So if $a_n=10$, then $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{26}>10$.  Is there some condition missing?

Comment: @soobster so, yo have to prove that the sequence is decreasing?

Comment: The sequence is strictly increasing if and only if the starting point (not sure where your sequence starts) lies in the interval $\left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt 3},+\frac2{\sqrt{3}}\right)$.  If the sequence start with $a_0$, then this means $|a_0|<\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}$.  If the sequence starts with $a_1$, then this means $|a_1|<\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}$.  On the other hand, if the starting point is greater than $+\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}$, then the sequence is strictly decreasing.  If the starting point is less than $-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$, then the sequence is strictly decreasing after one term.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yes, the range of the initial value was missing. I have added it on the title. Thank you so much for pointing out.

Comment: @Batominovski Thank you so much for pointing out. It was stated in the question and I missed it. I am so sorry for the confusion.

Comment: My hint is to show that the function $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ defined by $f(x)=\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{4}}$ for all $x\geq 0$ satisfies $f(x)>x$ for $x$ in the interval $\left[0,\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$.  Furthermore, show that $f$ maps the interval $\left[0,\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$ into itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n^2=1+\frac{a_{n-1}^2}{4}=\frac{1}{4}\left(4+a_{n-1}^2\right)=\frac{1}{4^2}\left(4^2+1\cdot4+a_{n-2}^2\right)=\frac{1}{4^3}\left(4^3+4^2+4+a_{n-3}^2\right)$
Hence, a recursive formula can be written as follows: $$ a_{n+1}^2=\frac{1}{4^n}\left(4^n+4^{n-1}+...4+a_1\right)=\frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{4^n-1}{4^n}+\frac{a_1^2}{4^n}$$.

$\therefore\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}$ irrespective of the choice of $a_1$. 
Also $a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2=\frac{4-3a_n^2}{4}>0 \forall a_n<\frac{2}{\sqrt3}$. 
Can you do the rest?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: 
It remains to show that
$$
\forall n\, a_n<\frac2{\sqrt{3}}.
$$
For $n=1$ it is in comments.