# What does this recursively defined sequence converge to?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $0 < a_0 < \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$ and define $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{1 +
>  \frac{a_n^2}{4}}$. Prove that $(a_n)$ converges. Find and prove its
> limit.

Here is a plan for the proof. I wish to try using the monotone convergence theorem, which requires the sequence to be bounded and monotone.

Now, I think that the sequence is increasing only when it is in that interval $0 < a_n < \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$. But I am not sure how to formally put that into a proof (working on induction right now).  Next, I should show the sequence is increasing (induction again?). Lastly, apply the MCT, and use algebraic limit theorem to take the limit on the defined $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{1 +\frac{a_n^2}{4}}$.

Does this sound like something that would work? Thanks.

Comment: If you try, you'll find it works by induction.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3523815/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3513861/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{1+{x^2 \over 4}}$ and note that $f$ maps $I=[0,2]$ into itself. Also note that $f'(x) = {x \over 4} {1 \over \sqrt{1+{x^2 \over 4}} }$ which is increasing on $I$, and $f'(2) = {1 \over 2\sqrt{2}} <1$. Applying the
[Banach fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) shows that the fixed point iteration $x_{n+1}= f(x_n)$ converges for any starting point $x_0 \in I$ to a unique fixed point $x^*$. Hence $x^* = \sqrt{1+{(x^*)^2 \over 4}}$ and solving this shows that $x^* = {2 \over \sqrt{3}}$.

Here are hints for another proof (albeit this is a 'working backwards from the answer' sort of proof):
Let $x^* = {2 \over \sqrt{3}}$ and note that if $x \in [0,x^*]$ then ${3x^2 \over 4} \le 1$ and so $x^2 \le 1+ {x^2 \over 4} \le (x^*)^2$. In particular, if $x_n \in [0,x^*]$, then $x_n \le x_{n+1} \le x^*$. Conclude that $x_n$ converges and use continuity to show that the limit is $x^*$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Will delete my comment as it is no longer needed and +1.

Comment: Nice! Although I believe this is expected to be done without taking derivatives, as we have yet to define that. I have been working on an induction proof, I will maybe post it and see. But thanks for typing this up.

Comment: @Oran I added some hints for a more direct proof, however, I worked this out knowing the answer and working backwards, as such.